# Custom Layers for recursive interation bitween layers

Tags: customization, keras, layer, convolution

I have a question. I'm trying to make a CNN, the return of model feeds first Dence layer. Can I help?
e.g:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same',
                        input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

I Should have the output value feeds layer Dense (512)

1. Dense (512 + 10, name='d1') output  d2 with input here.
2. Activation()
3. Dropout(522)
4. Dense (10, name='d2')

Comment: How many iterations of it do you want to achieve?

Comment: I need the output model return to dense layer for create a RNN. This basic mind.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I think so https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0eJkvcHNZP4cDVZZ3M0U1pYaHM/view